# How to populate empty column with values from previous time stamp

Tags: r, time-series, populate

I'm conducting a network analysis, and I have location data in a "Target" column. I want to populate a "Source" column with the Target data from the previous timestamp. Is this possible?

```
ID      Date          Year    Month   Day    Time    Target     Source
650     18/07/2019    2019    Jul     18     21:32   Caledonia  NA
650     19/07/2019    2019    Jul     19     23:47   Digby      NA
650     27/07/2019    2019    Jul     27     19:24   Caledonia  NA
```

I want the Source column to populate with the previous "Target" for that ID

```
ID      Date          Year    Month   Day    Time    Target     Source
650     18/07/2019    2019    Jul     18     21:32   Caledonia  NA
650     19/07/2019    2019    Jul     19     23:47   Digby      Caledonia
650     27/07/2019    2019    Jul     27     19:24   Caledonia  Digby
```

Comment: the function in data.table is called shift

Comment: Have a look at the [slide](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DataCombine/versions/0.2.21/topics/slide) function and examples. What you describe is adding a lagged variable. Edit: I prefer shift from data.table mentioned above, but slide is a bit easier for data frames if you have a grouping variable and haven't used data.tables before e.g the Id column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the lag function from dplyr will be a big help for you.

In the example code below I'm
1) creating a timestamp of date and time
2) Explicitly sorting by this new variable so that lag can know what the preceding value is
3) grouping by ID so that we get the lagging Target for each ID separately
4) running the lag function and specifying what the original value should be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

t <- tibble(
        ID = c(650, 650, 650), 
        Date = c('18/07/2019', '19/07/2019', '27/07/2019'), 
        Time = c('21:32', '23:47', '19:24'), 
        Target = c('Caledonia', 'Digby', 'Caledonia'))

t <- t %>% 
        mutate(date_time = as.POSIXct(
                paste(Date, Time, sep = ' '), 
                format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')) %>%
        arrange(date_time) %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate(Source = lag(Target, default = NA)) %>% 
        ungroup()

t

     ID Date       Time  Target    date_time           Source   
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>    
1   650 18/07/2019 21:32 Caledonia 2019-07-18 21:32:00 NA       
2   650 19/07/2019 23:47 Digby     2019-07-19 23:47:00 Caledonia
3   650 27/07/2019 19:24 Caledonia 2019-07-27 19:24:00 Digby  

## to replace initial values with `Target`

t %>% 
        mutate(Source = case_when(
                !is.na(Source) ~ Source,
                is.na(Source) ~ Target))
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much!

My only issue now is replacing the NAs for the the first timestamp for each ID with the same info. 

I tried this, but it didn't work: 
> all.data$Source[all.data$Source == "NA"] <- "Caledonia"

Comment: I've added an example that should take care of that for you. 

Its essentially using the logic you've described above, but in a more 'tidyverse' way. 
So case_when is checking for NAs in the Source variable, and then overwriting any with the value in the Target value.